# Can't start DrRacket

Tags: install-from-source

I downloaded the unix source for racket5.3 http://racket-lang.org/download/ and followed the build instructions, it installed succesfully.

I tried running ./drracket from the created /bin directory but it results in the following error message:

```
ffi-lib: couldn't open "libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0" (libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)   
context...:
/home/jon/scr-downloads/racket-5.3/collects/mred/private/wx/gtk/utils.rkt: [running body]
/home/jon/scr-downloads/racket-5.3/collects/mred/private/wx/gtk/init.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/jon/scr-downloads/racket-5.3/collects/mred/private/wx/gtk/platform.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/jon/scr-downloads/racket-5.3/collects/mred/private/wx/platform.rkt: [running body]
/home/jon/scr-downloads/racket-5.3/collects/mred/private/kernel.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/jon/scr-downloads/racket-5.3/collects/mred/private/mred.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/jon/scr-downloads/racket-5.3/collects/mred/mred.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/jon/scr-downloads/racket-5.3/collects/mred/main.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/jon/scr-downloads/racket-5.3/collects/racket/gui/base.rkt: [traversing imports]
/home/jon/scr-downloads/racket-5.3/collects/drracket/drracket.rkt: [traversing imports]
```

I would appreciate any help in fixing this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is caused by incorrect linking.

The easiest solution is to simply install it from a ppa.

The racket devs maintain [this](https://launchpad.net/~plt/+archive/racket) ppa and it is kept up to date.

To install it run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:plt/racket
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install racket
```

Remove any files you created when trying to build from source and racket will be installed.